# Trying to automate imacro

Tags: javascript, imacros

Im trying to make my macro extract a link from the website "Adoteumcara.com.br" and open in a new tab; like in iconosquare code. I couldt find my mistake.

When I record, the macro looks like:

```
VERSION BUILD=8350307 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.adoteumcara.com.br/mySearch/results
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:mask&&TXT:
BACK
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:mask&&TXT:
```

But I need something like:

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
    SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
    TAB T=1
    TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=div ATTR=pic&&HREF:#/profile/* EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=2
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    WAIT SECONDS=10
    TAB CLOSE
```

Can someone helpme to find my error?

Comment: I would advise you to make this question more clear.